# Image Matrix to String OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, string, opencv, matrix, type-conversion

I have to convert an image matrix in c++ in a string. 
I have found two way:

```
const char *inputD = (const char*)(img.data);
Size imageSiz = img.size();
int w = imageSiz.width;
int h = imageSiz.height;
int ch = img.channels();
_return.append(inputD, w*h*ch);
```

where _return is:

```
std::string& _return
```

and this one is always working. But I have also find another way:

```
string matAsStringL (imgL.begin<unsigned char>(), imgL.end<unsigned char>());
_return.push_back(matAsStringL);
```

where of course _return is different:

```
std::vector<std::string> & _return
```

But the second one is not working with colored images, but only on grayscale. Why? I would like to understand.

The error I get from the second one is:
assertion failed (elemSize() == sizeof(_Tp)) in unknow function. In mat.hpp

An example is:

```
img1 = imread(filenameL , 0); //Gray_scale
string matAsStringI(img1.begin<unsigned char>(), img1.end<unsigned char>());
//now in matAsString I have the info I need
cvtColor(img1, coloredImage1, CV_GRAY2RGB);
string matAsStringC(coloredImage1.begin<unsigned char>(), coloredImage1.end<unsigned char>()); //crash here with the assertion error
```

is not working for coloredImage1 but works for img1. If I change for coloredImage1 and I use the first method it works fine.

Comment: did you want a *text* representation ?

Comment: what do you mean "not working with colored images" ? you get an error? or shows wrong data? just part of the data?

Comment: I get an assertion failed (elemSize() == sizeof(_Tp)) in unknow function. In mat.hpp

Answer (score 4):

You can use iterator of mat directly in string constructor but you will get only first unsigned char of each pixel instead of all data.

You have to do compromise with your first and second solution such as

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
  const char *path = "/home/gerard_gaudeau/Downloads/image.jpg";
  cv::Mat mat = cv::imread(path);
  cv::Size size = mat.size();

  int total = size.width * size.height * mat.channels();
  std::cout << "Mat size = " << total << std::endl;

  std::vector<uchar> data(mat.ptr(), mat.ptr() + total);
  std::string s(data.begin(), data.end());                   
  std::cout << "String size = " << s.length() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the for the colored images I get just one color and not all the matrix right? That is why it fail? I have added an example and the error to the question

Comment: In fact, I tried your code with an RGB image and I hadn't assertion about the number of dimensions... strange. Final string size was 1/3 of image size.